# Dynamic "cleaned" column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column in table that I am using in a pile of other views but it needs cleaning all the time.
So I'm using a bunch of TRIM() LOWER() and REPLACE() to strip out all anomalies in this column eg removing all '/', 'â€™', '-', '', ':', 'Ã‰', '''', 'É'), '.', ''' etc so when I do a group instead of 3 or 8 versions of a value it gets cleaned up into one.

Now i feel I'm missing a trick in how I approach this because anytime i reference my column I have to clean it up with my encasing code there and then which gets very messy.

Now WITHOUT creating a derived VIEW with the cleaned column is there another way to handle this? - some sort of auto cleaning function or way to have a derived column in my base table.

Cheers :)

Comment: How does the bad data get in there in the first place?  Can up update data in the table after it's inserted?

Comment: Not sure what your goal is here? Are you saying the data is of poor quality and you want to fix it? is so, use an `UPDATE` statement. If you mean the data being put into the database is of poor quality, then that isn't the database's fault; you need to have some kind of validation on the data prior to it's insertion (i.e. at appliciation level) that doesn't allow non-permitted characters.

Comment: The data is of poor quality, but I want to preserve that, I just don't want to replicate the cleanup code all over the place. The comments below on computed columns and functions look like what I'm after. You are right about the application layer, but I have limited control over that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> or way to have a derived column in my base table.

Add a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017) that applies your cleaning functions to your base table.

Comment: Or a _persisted_ computed column. Indexed as needed.

Comment: Persisted is definitely the better idea, otherwise it is still performing the cleaning every time it is queried. The only drawback is that the cleaning has to be completely deterministic. Worst case, if you can't create a persisted computed column it would still be better to create a column and run an sp to put cleaned values in that column.

Comment: Persisted is better performance-wise, but OP's main question was how to consolidate the cleaning code into one place.  This goal is achieved whether the computed column is persisted or not.   Yet another options is to simply add a column for the cleaned data, and populate it in a trigger.

Comment: My computed column code is pretty meaty. Getting an error "Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding." - any ideas of how to stop it timing out?

Comment: When does the timeout occur?   When you're creating the column, inserting rows, or selecting rows?

Comment: Saving. Its ok I got it with some fiddling with timeout settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use functions:

```
create function dbo.RemoveSpecialChars (@s varchar(256)) returns varchar(256)
   with schemabinding
begin
   if @s is null
      return null
   declare @s2 varchar(256)
   set @s2 = ''
   declare @l int
   set @l = len(@s)
   declare @p int
   set @p = 1
   while @p <= @l begin
      declare @c int
      set @c = ascii(substring(@s, @p, 1))
      if @c between 48 and 57 or @c between 65 and 90 or @c between 97 and 122
         set @s2 = @s2 + char(@c)
      set @p = @p + 1
      end
   if len(@s2) = 0
      return null
   return @s2
   end
```

then call it:

```
declare @mystring nvarchar(50) = '"!"%$£GETONLYTHISPART_:çé'

select dbo.RemoveSpecialChars (@mystring)
```

[EXAMPLE here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e22c3/1)